# Ionic 4: Tabs with routing doesn't display content

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I was using this tutorial https://alligator.io/ionic/ionic-4-tabs/ to create Routing for my Ionic Tabs, but unfortunately the displayed content is always hidden and can't be shown.

My home.page.html looks like this:

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-tabs style="display: contents;">

  <ion-tab-bar slot="top">

    <ion-tab-button tab="popular">
      <ion-label>SOme text</ion-label>
      <ion-icon name="heart"></ion-icon>
      <ion-badge>6</ion-badge>
    </ion-tab-button>

  </ion-tab-bar>
</ion-tabs>
</ion-header>
```

I defined the routings inside a home-routing.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'tabs',
        component: HomePage,
        children:
            [
                {
                    path: 'popular',
                    children:
                        [
                            {
                                path: '',
                                loadChildren: '../popular/popular.module#PopularPageModule'
                            }
                        ]
                }
           ]
     }
]
```

And my popular.page.module.html looks like this:

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar color="primary">
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
<h1>Hallo</h1>
</ion-content>
```

I excpected so the h1-Tag "Hallo", but unfortunately it doesn't show anything. The interesting thing indeed, is that the h1-Tag is shown in Developer-Tools in the Browser.

Any ideas?

Comment: Edit: I found out that the content from the Popular-Tab is always included in the `<div class="tabs-inner">`- Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has caused me a head headache XD. you shouldnt be putting your tabs in your header. the taps component/element is generated at the level above the page, where as the header element is generated within the page so sticking the tabs in the header is causeing all sorts of crazyness.

I went through the tutorial and got it to display correctly [image]

home.page.html -

```
<ion-tabs>
<ion-tab-bar slot="top" color="primary">
    <ion-tab-button tab="tab1">
      <ion-icon name="home"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Home</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

<ion-tab-button tab="tab2">
      <ion-label>SOme text</ion-label>
      <ion-icon name="heart"></ion-icon>
      <ion-badge>6</ion-badge>
    </ion-tab-button>
  </ion-tab-bar>
</ion-tabs>
```

please comment for stuff you want me to add

Comment: LOL, thank you so much. I am completly new to Ionic and Typescripting.